# Rename Java file but keep history in IBM Rational Synergy 7.1

Tags: java, refactoring, cm-synergy

In the very big Java project I'm currently participating in, we use IBM Rational Synergy 7.1 as SCM. Now, a huge amount of rename and move refactorings are coming up due to changes in the architecture.

We would prefer to have Eclipse as the leading side in the refactoring, with (roughly) the following workflow:

1. Apply the refactoring using the JDT tools
2. Move the files in Synergy in order to keep the history of the file (if possible automated with Synergy CLI)

If we just do the refactoring and sync, the old file will be marked as deleted and the new file will have version 1. This is obviously not desired.

Is there a way to achieve step 2 with the Synergy CLI considering the old version with the old name is the one that is currently on the server while the new version only exists in the work area for the time being? You may assume that I have all the necessary information about the old file in the database (instance, name, version etc) available, I reckon I have to gather that beforehand.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going to use the Synergy CLI for this and have roughly this workflow:

1. Do Refactoring in Eclipse
2. Rename the target file of the refactoring (adding a suffix)
3. Use the CLI command `ccm move` to move the files in synergy
4. Delete the file that was created in the workarea and remove the suffix from the file in step 2
5. sync the project

I ommited things like setting a task, those have to be done.